# Intersection observer to detect in viewport Images in the overflow scroll container not working

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Intersection observer is firing event for all the image in the overflow scroll container not when they come in the view port.

Using the intersection observer to lazy load images: 
https://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/lazy-loading-images-using-intersection-observer/10163

```
<ul class="product-horizontal-list">
  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j0vb3bk0/t-shirt/h/b/x/m-arek0253grey-melange-arrow-sports-original-imaeskqnukxhvhth.jpeg?q=70"></li>

  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j6dxaq80/t-shirt/h/y/u/m-28771-0061blacks-levi-s-original-imaewv46jxf4wyxa.jpeg?q=70"></li>
  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j7qi9ow0/t-shirt/x/r/z/m-bts026-billion-original-imaexwxvczbnfz8a.jpeg?q=70"></li>
  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j4hc5u80/t-shirt/u/w/j/m-17p3dtpj3033i501-united-colors-of-benetton-original-imaevcrzqas8uwvy.jpeg?q=70"></li>
  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j0vb3bk0/t-shirt/n/a/x/m-arek0255me-yellow-arrow-sports-original-imaeskqzm5hrn8hk.jpeg?q=70"></li>
  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j6pctjk0/t-shirt/v/e/8/m-akss3356navy-arrow-sport-original-imaex3xgzhjvdzxu.jpeg?q=70"></li>
  <li> <img class="js-lazy-image centered" data-src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/j6gs6fk0/t-shirt/e/v/n/m-24608-0004blues-levi-s-original-imaewxcwweyz9fh3.jpeg?q=70"></li>

</ul>

  // Get all of the images that are marked up to lazy load
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.js-lazy-image');
const config = {
  // If the image gets within 50px in the Y axis, start the download.
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.01
};

let imageCount = images.length;
let observer;

// If we don't have support for intersection observer, loads the images immediately
if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
  loadImagesImmediately(images);
} else {
  // It is supported, load the images
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, config);

  // foreach() is not supported in IE
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    let image = images[i];
    if (image.classList.contains('js-lazy-image--handled')) {
      continue;
    }

    observer.observe(image);
  }
}

/**
 * Fetchs the image for the given URL
 * @param {string} url 
 */
function fetchImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = resolve;
    image.onerror = reject;
  });
}

/**
 * Preloads the image
 * @param {object} image 
 */
function preloadImage(image) {
  const src = image.dataset.src;
  if (!src) {
    return;
  }

  return fetchImage(src).then(() => { applyImage(image, src); });
}

/**
 * Load all of the images immediately
 * @param {NodeListOf<Element>} images 
 */
function loadImagesImmediately(images) {
  // foreach() is not supported in IE
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    let image = images[i];
    preloadImage(image);
  }
}

/**
 * Disconnect the observer
 */
function disconnect() {
  if (!observer) {
    return;
  }

  observer.disconnect();
}

/**
 * On intersection
 * @param {array} entries 
 */
function onIntersection(entries) {
  // Disconnect if we've already loaded all of the images
  if (imageCount === 0) {
    observer.disconnect();
  }

  // Loop through the entries
  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) { 
    let entry = entries[i];
    // Are we in viewport?
    console.log('in viewport')
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      imageCount--;

      // Stop watching and load the image
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      preloadImage(entry.target);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Apply the image
 * @param {object} img 
 * @param {string} src 
 */
function applyImage(img, src) {
  // Prevent this from being lazy loaded a second time.
  img.classList.add('js-lazy-image--handled');
  img.src = src;
  img.classList.add('fade-in');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anshuPurohit/h84k9zkv/

Answer (score 4):

The good news is your intersection observer is working. I haven't tested all of your methods, but I did get it to behave the way you want it to in your example fiddle. You need to set at least a min-width on the images. Since images are embedded content, their initial width is going to be 0. And the intersection observer makes its calculations before your images load, which means all of those elements will be visible to it when it runs.

You also currently have your threshold set very low. Your current threshold of '0.01' means that only 1% of the element needs to be visible for the callback to execute. I would recommend setting it at '0.25' and experiment with it from there.

Tl;dr. Increase your threshold, set a min-width on the image and see how it goes.

One other recommendation for your image scroller, which will help maintain responsive images without resorting to assigning an explicit width to your images, is to use an intrinsic placeholder. 
http://daverupert.com/2015/12/intrinsic-placeholders-with-picture/